# Trying to understand IPv6 scopes

Tags: ipv6

Currently I have the following image in my head (please correct me if I'm wrong):

```
 +--------------------------+
 | +----------------------+ |
 | | +------------------+ | |
 | | |       HOST       | | |
 | | | interface-local  | | |
 | | +------------------+ | |
 | |         LAN          | |
 | |      link-local      | |
 | |      site-local      | |
 | |                      | |
 | +----------------------+ |
 |           WAN            |
 |    organization-local    |
 |          global          |
 +--------------------------+
```

- Packets sent to/from *interface-local* address never leave the host.
- *link-local* or *site-local* provides connectivity between hosts on the same LAN.
- *organization-local* and *global* provides connectivity in the internet.

If I'm right about all the scopes then *link-local* and *site-local* seem very similar. Why then they coexist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. site local was [deprecated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3879) in 2004
2. ULA Address can be used for internal only routed networks, link local is local subnet only and does not pass the gateway.
3. global unicast is typically all you need, if you're new to IPv6 you only need to worry about global unicast addressing, use it for everything except specialty systems (SAN for instance)
4. A full list of IPv6 Standards (not all RFCs are accepted) are listed in [RFC820](https://www.internetsociety.org/blog/2017/07/rfc-8200-ipv6-has-been-standardized/)

   +--------------------------+
   | +----------------------+ |
   | | +------------------+ | |
   | | |       HOST       | | |
   | | | interface-local  | | |
   | | +------------------+ | |
   | |  L2 Domain (Gateway) | |
   | |      link-local      | |
   | +----------------------+ |
   |          WAN/LAN         |
   |          global          |
   +--------------------------+

Comment: So if I needed to test something between two hosts on the LAN I would use either *unique local address* `fdxx:` or *global address* `2xxx:`/`3xxx:`. To test connectivity between router and the host I would use *link-local* `fe8x:`. I cannot ping *link-local* address on the other host?

Comment: you would always use global/unique-local addresses to test, including between host and upstream gateway, and additionally link-local for host-gateway but essentially yes.